# Clean Realm database before build for release

Tags: ios, realm

How can I clear the Realm database before archive and send to Itunes Connect? I made an app that I create new objects in database for testing in the debug environment but I would like to remove them when I send to Apple iTunes for distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a compiler flag to tell you if the app is in debug mode, and only add those test objects if the flag is defined. i.e. Add `-DDEBUG` in `Build Settings > Other Swift Flags > Debug`, and then do

```
#if DEBUG
// Add test objects
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your database being saved? If you haven't modified the `fileURL` property of the default Realm `Configuration` object at all, then by default, it will be saved to your app's 'Documents' directory on the device, which is *not* included in your app's bundle when it is packaged for the App Store. When the app is deployed to a new device, a new, empty Realm database file will be created on it.

And like Stefan said, you can use the `#if DEBUG` macro to explicitly isolate code that may be generating test data while you're working on the app.

The only time a Realm file will be included with an app bundle is if you explicitly embedded it in your app as a resource (Just like any other assets you may have included).